# How can I change the value of the Z rotation inside the script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I rotate the bone, I see that it only rotates on the Z axis.

2D gun:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject forBone;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
         
    }
}
```

How can I change that value inside the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the axis of rotation by changing the values of the x, y, and z components of the rotation property of the forBone transform. The default value is Vector3.zero, which means that there is no rotation.

To rotate the bone around the X axis:

```
void Update()
{
    forBone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(10, 0, 0);
}
```

This will rotate the bone around the X axis by 10 degrees each frame. You can change the value of 10 to any other angle you want.

You can also use the Rotate method to rotate the bone around a specific axis. For example, this code will rotate the bone around the Y axis by 20 degrees:

```
void Update()
{
    forBone.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The Vector3.up vector represents the Y axis. The Time.deltaTime value is the amount of time that has passed since the last frame. This ensures that the rotation is consistent, regardless of the frame rate.